# Problems with running test with --config

Tags: nightwatch.js

I'm currently trying to run a nightwatch test by passing in the conf.js file via the --config tag. The conf.js file is in the directory below where the nightwatch command will be run from. Looks like this

```
.
└── project root
    ├── tests
    ├── bin
        └── selenium.jar
        └── chromedriver
    └── other
        └── nightwatch.conf.js
        ├── custom-assertions
```

Relative part of the conf.js file looks like this

```
    "src_folders" : [
      "../tests"
    ],
    "custom_commands_path" : "custom-commands",
    "selenium": {
      "start_process": true,
      "server_path": "../bin/selenium.jar",
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": 4444,
      "cli_args": {
        "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "../bin/chromedriver"
      }
    },
```

The problem i'm having is if I try to run the test from project root with

```
nightwatch --config other/nightwatch.conf.js --verbose
```

I get the following error

```
Starting selenium server... There was an error while starting the 
Selenium server:

Error: Unable to access jarfile ../bin/selenium.jar
```

However, if I run it from the other folder and don't specify the --config (because i'm running it from the folder where the conf lives) it works fine. So i'm thinking i'm doing something wrong but I don't know what. Anyone any ideas?

Other info -

1. The directory set up has to be the way outlined above
2. The tests have to be ran from the project root
3. The project root is in /home dir (I don't think it's a permissions
   issues but it could be I guess)
4. Nightwatch is installed globally

Let me know if I can provide any other info. 
Thanks
Ally

edit 
changed 'run project from root' to 'run project from project root'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust your config code to run based on the directory of the `package.json` or `gulpfile.js`. Try adjusting your code to the following

```
    "src_folders" : [
     "tests"
    ],
    "custom_commands_path" : "custom-commands",
    "selenium": {
      "start_process": true,
    "server_path": "bin/selenium.jar",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 4444,
    "cli_args": {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "bin/chromedriver"
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

Unfortunately that didn't work, just got the same error. I changed it to point to the /bin folder in the Nightwatch install directory (located /usr/lib/node_modules/nightwatch as it was installed globally), That seem to fix the issue but now I get the same error with `../tests` folder (also located a directory above the nightwatch.conf.js file).

This doesn't seem like this should be this complicated to be honest. Kinda at a loss why it isn't working.

Comment: Actually no, it is working. Don't know why it didn't this morning but i assume it was something to do with lack of sleep. Thank you for the quick advice on how to fix my issue.